# Code continue to execute in the same class even after redirecting using Intent

Tags: android

I have 2 class,  MainActivity.class and Down.class. Upon a button click in MainActivity.class and based on some conditions , i want to redirect to Down.class.  But the code continue to execute in MainActivity.class  even after the following  , what might be the reason for that?

```
if(x==1)
{
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Down.class);
    myintent.putExtra("error", col_key);
    startActivity(myintent);
}


int var_l=0;
```

FYI- The above code is getting executed (I have checked in Debug mode).

Down.class

```
public class Down  extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView var_textView_down;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.down);


        var_textView_down = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ui_textView_down);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String error=extras.getString("error");
        var_textView_down.setText(error);



    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also put the code of what your conditions are? On the basis of which you're redirecting the user.

Comment: @hsm59, that does not matter, because i have seen the above code is getting executed in Debug mode.

Comment: Either you need to stop the code block from executing yourself or finish the previous activity in your case MainActivity

Comment: So based on that you're saying the code is getting executed but the Down activity does not open?

Comment: @santalu, i have tried by adding finish() at the end of above code, but it didnt change anything

Comment: show us the code you mention that continue being executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a return to stop further code being executed.

```
if(x==1)
{
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Down.class);
    myintent.putExtra("error", col_key);
    startActivity(myintent);
    //put a return here
    return;
}


int var_l=0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that `startActivity(intent)` and `startActivityForResult(intent)` is asynchronous method. So your next line of codes will be executed without waiting until the activity is created and shown.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved. I have used `return` as shown below.

```
if(x==1)
{
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Down.class);
    myintent.putExtra("error", col_key);
    startActivity(myintent);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from ישו אוהב אותך `startActivity()` is async in the way that the following lines of code will continue to execute. As stated at the [Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) `startActivity()` does not mean the activity will immediately start. Quote:

> startActivity launches a new activity. You will not receive any information about when the activity exits

To verify:

```
// override onStop in your MainActivity
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "activity stopped");
}

// override onPause in your MainActivity
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "activity paused");
}


// wherever the "Down" activity is started within MainActivity
{
    Log.d("MainActivity", "about to start Down");
    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Down.class);
    startActivity(myintent);    
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Continuing work");
}


// add to onCreate() in the Down Activity
Log.d("Down", "Hello from Down");
```

You will get the following execution order:

1. MainActivity: about to start Down
2. MainActivity: Continuing work
3. MainActivity: activity paused
4. Down: Hello from Down
5. MainActivity: activity stopped

returning is one way to stop the further execution within the same block. I recommend having a look into the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#soafa) documentation.